# How to create index in Entity Framework 6.2 with fluent configuration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

Is there a way to create an index on a property/column using fluent configuration, instead of using the new [`IndexAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_10) ?

Comment: An index is a database concept, not an entity model concept. Even if you could specify an index with an attribute or through the fluent API it wouldn't actually DO anything in your application. It'd just be an instruction for EF to use when creating the database. I believe such instructions belong in code-first migrations, which is entirely concerned with manipulating database schema.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Well 26.10.2017 Entity Framework 6.2 was [officially released](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/26/entity-framework-6-2-runtime-released/).
It includes a [possibility](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/274) to define indexes with ease via Fluent API. Ho it is to use was already [announced](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/05/23/announcing-ef-6-2-beta-1/#fluent-api-to-define-indexes-274) in the beta of 6.2.

Now you can use the `HasIndex()` method, followed by `IsUnique()` if it should be an unique index.

Just a small comparison (before/after) example:

```
// before 
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .Property(e => e.Name)
        .HasColumnAnnotation(
            IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, 
            new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute { IsUnique = true }));

// after
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasIndex(p => p.Name)
    .IsUnique();

// multi column index
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasIndex(p => new { p.Name, p.Firstname })
    .IsUnique();
```

It is also possible to mark the index as clustered with `.IsClustered()`.

---

**EDIT #1**

Added an example for multi column index and additional information how to mark an index as clustered.

---

**EDIT #2**

As additional information, in EF Core 2.1 it is exactly the same like in EF 6.2 now.
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/modeling/indexes) is the MS Doc artcile as reference.

Comment: This is great! I suppose that if I have multicolumn index it would be something like: .HasIndex(p => new {p.Name, p.Xyz})

Comment: Oh, sorry, sure. It should be `new`. I will fix it.

Comment: Could you please show how can we write the same code in Core 2.x?

Comment: As far as I know it should be the same code like shown under "after" and "multi column index".

Comment: Hi I want to add HasIndex methos using Roslyn part, Can you help to do ?

Answer (score 88):

Currently there is no ["first class support"](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1969) for creating a index via the fluent API, but what you can do is via the fluent API you can mark properties as having attributes from the Annotation API. This will allow you to add the `Index` attribute via a fluent interface.

Here are some examples from the work item from Issues site for EF.

Create a index on a single column:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .Property(e => e.MyProperty)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(
        IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, 
        new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute()));
```

Multiple indexes on a single column:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .Property(e => e.MyProperty)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(
        IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, 
        new IndexAnnotation(new[]
            {
                new IndexAttribute("Index1"),
                new IndexAttribute("Index2") { IsUnique = true }
            }));
```

Multi-Column indexes:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .Property(e => e.MyProperty1)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(
        IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
        new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("MyIndex", 1)));

modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .Property(e => e.MyProperty2)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(
        IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, 
        new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("MyIndex", 2)));
```

Using the above techniques will cause `.CreateIndex()` calls to be automatically created for you in your `Up()` function when you scaffold your next migration (or be automatically created in the database if you are not using migrations).

Comment: that might add the index on the column but that wont remove the clustered index created on primary key . The hasKey creates the clustered index on primary keys which aren't by default gets removed. That has to be explicitly removed from the migration file created by stating clusered:false in `.Primarykey(x=>x.id,clustered:false)` method

Comment: I tried the `HasAnnotation` method and there is NO method like this. but I found a method which name `HasColumnAnnotation` which accepts the parameters which you provide. Do you need to update your answer or am I wrong?

Comment: @HakamFostok I took the example directly from the EF site. Perhaps the name changed in one of the versions or there is a typo in the original version.

Comment: See right down the bottom of the following link from a design meeting earlier this year: "Rename HasAnnotation to HasColumnAnnotation (plus other relevant places in the code base).".

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design%20Meeting%20Notes%20%E2%80%93%20January%2016%2C%202014

Answer (score 36):

I've created a some extension methods and wrapped them in a nuget package to make this much easier.

Install the [`EntityFramework.IndexingExtensions`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.IndexingExtensions) nuget package.

Then you can do the following:

```
public class MyDataContext : DbContext
{
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
        .HasIndex("IX_Customers_Name",          // Provide the index name.
            e => e.Property(x => x.LastName),   // Specify at least one column.
            e => e.Property(x => x.FirstName))  // Multiple columns as desired.

        .HasIndex("IX_Customers_EmailAddress",  // Supports fluent chaining for more indexes.
            IndexOptions.Unique,                // Supports flags for unique and clustered.
            e => e.Property(x => x.EmailAddress)); 
  }
}
```

[The project and source code are here](https://github.com/mj1856/EntityFramework.IndexingExtensions).  Enjoy!

Comment: I really like the package but it seems the index name is sometimes missing after scaffolding in the up script. It only appeared for me when using 4 or more properties in my index. I'm working with EF 6.1.3.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid - would you please log the issue [here](https://github.com/mj1856/EntityFramework.IndexingExtensions/issues) with supporting details?  Also be sure you have version 1.0.1, since there was [a bug](https://github.com/mj1856/EntityFramework.IndexingExtensions/issues/2) in 1.0.0.

Comment: I do have version 1.0.1. I will log the issue but cannot do so at this moment.

Comment: How do I add index participating column order to descending? By default .HasIndex("IX_Customers_EmailAddress", IndexOptions.Unique, ... creates ascending order for all participating columns in index.

Comment: @GDroid - Unfortunately, this isn't exposed by EF's `IndexAttribute` class, so I cannot include it in my library.

Answer (score 27):

From EF 6.1 onward the attribute `[Index]` is supported. 
Use `[Index(IsUnique = true)]` for unique index. 
 
Here is the [link from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Index)

```
public class User 
{ 
    public int UserId { get; set; } 

    [Index(IsUnique = true)] 
    [StringLength(200)] 
    public string Username { get; set; } 

    public string DisplayName { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @manetsus Very well. I added a code snippet to reflect the change.

Comment: The string length is needed otherwise you see a 'is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index' exception. My collegue prefers the modelBuilder solution on the Conntext so your not cluttering up your User class, which I guess is valid.

Comment: What about indexes with multiple columns for uniqueness?  Quite common to have a multi-column Unique Key index...

Comment: @enorl76 That is also supported. For each columns you would need to use an attribute like the following,
      `[Index("IX_BlogIdAndRating", 2)]`
      `public int Rating { get; set; }`
      `[Index("IX_BlogIdAndRating", 1)]`
      `public int BlogId { get; set; }`

Here the reference from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#multiple-column-indexes)

Comment: @DarieDorlus yes thank you.  Basically you're saying as long as IsUnique=true on at least one of the Index attributes, and on all the Index attributes that the index name matches, the columns will get added into a unique-key constraint index.  This is what I ended up finding out locally.

Answer (score 26):

Without an explicit name:

```
[Index]
public int Rating { get; set; }
```

With a specific name:

```
[Index("PostRatingIndex")] 
public int Rating { get; set; }
```

Comment: Index seems to be depricated :(

Comment: @HamedZakeryMiab Which version of Entity Framework are you using? Index was not deprecated.

Comment: excuse me, I forgot to include `EntityFramework`. it's included in that assembly. just confused about the NS.

Comment: @HamedZakeryMiab yeah that was super confusing! I thought it was part of System.DataAnnotations! It is definitely the entity framework package

Comment: the question contains the following statement `instead of using the new IndexAttribute` did you notice it ?

Answer (score 8):

Entity Framework 6

```
Property(c => c.MyColumn)
        .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_MyIndex")));
```

And add using:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Annotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the INDEX data annotaion
[Code First Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Index)

Comment: Maximum key length is 900 bytes for nvarchar and 450 bytes for varchar. If you are using code first the string properties will be nvarchar and you should include the attribute "StringLength" as in [[StringLength(450)]

Comment: As of EF 6.1, this is the correct answer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations?redirectedfrom=MSDN#index

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use attributes on your POCO's, then you can always do it like the following:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE INDEX IX_NAME ON ...");
```

You can execute this statement in your custom `DbInitializer` derived class. I don't know any Fluent API way of doing this though.

Comment: Sure, Mert. At the moment I am using migrations and there in the Up() method you can also put: CreateIndex("dbo.Table1", "Column1", true, "Column1_IX") and in Down() DropIndex(("dbo.Table1", "Column1_IX"). I was just hoping that they added a fluent API too...

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of this

// Indexes

```
 this.HasIndex(e => e.IsActive)
            .HasName("IX_IsActive");
```

or

```
  this.Property(e => e.IsActive).HasColumnAnnotation(
            "Index",
            new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_IsActive")));
```

Answer (score 1):

I write an extension method for use in fluent EF to avoid extra code:

```
public static PrimitivePropertyConfiguration HasIndexAnnotation(
    this PrimitivePropertyConfiguration primitivePropertyConfiguration, 
    IndexAttribute indexAttribute = null
    )
{
    indexAttribute = indexAttribute ?? new IndexAttribute();

    return primitivePropertyConfiguration
        .HasColumnAnnotation(
            IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, 
            new IndexAnnotation(indexAttribute)
        );
}
```

then use it like this:

```
Property(t => t.CardNo)
    .HasIndexAnnotation();
```

or like this if index needs some configs:

```
Property(t => t.CardNo)
    .HasIndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Account") { IsUnique = true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, on **.net core** it will be :

```
[Index(nameof(AdvId), IsUnique = true)]
public class tblAdvertisement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AdvId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

So, attribute set is on class, not on member. Output migration looks like this after :

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_Advertisements_AdvId",
        table: "Advertisements",
        column: "AdvId",
        unique: true);
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
        name: "IX_Advertisements_AdvId",
        table: "Advertisements");

}
```

Comment: Yeah, but the question is how to use fluent API (I edited it to make that more clear. OP mentioned "code-first" vs "attributes", but of course attributes are also code-first).