# ASP.NET MVC | Create an Index on IdentityUser.Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In my project, my user class is inheriting from IdentityUser, and because i have alot of users and i'm performing alot of queries against the user email (which is an IdentityUser property) i wish to have it indexed.

How can one index properties of IdentityUser?

I was thinkin about overriding the Email property and put the [Index] annotation, but will this breaks something?

Note that my project is based on ASP.NET MVC 6 template, and i'm using Entity framework code-first approach.

Comment: So you are using code-first and entity framework?

Comment: Yes i do, i have edited my question to include this information, thanks :)

Comment: Is the email already a primary key for your table in the db? If so, there already is a primary index. Also this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618237/how-to-create-index-in-entity-framework-6-2-with-code-first

Comment: In IdentityUser, only the Id is a PrimaryKey, but will overriding the Email property and put the [Index] annotation will break anything? i find this to be a better approach than to edit the migration first schema because i might not always use it or i can accidently drop it, where the [Index] annotation will always be there

Comment: ideally there should be no side affect apart from small performance overhead while adding new user as it will get indexed

Comment: Ok, will the Original Email Annotation (which are added in the IdentityUser class such as maximumlength) will be applied in my overiding?